# How to create a meanplot by group (gender analysis) using ggplot 2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, mean, variance

Okay, I'd like to create the following plot in R using ggplot2:
[Gender based meanplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbpjk.jpg)

Here's the actual code to produce the output shown:

```
boxplot(mydata$socialanxiety~mydata$sex1,
+  horizontal=F, col = "gray", na.action=na.omit)

plotmeans(socialanxiety~sex1,xlab="Gender", ylab="Anxiety",
+ main="Mean Plot", data = mydata)
stripchart(mydata$socialanxiety~mydata$sex1,vertical=F,
+            xlab='Anxiety')
meanvec = tapply(mydata$socialanxiety,mydata$sex1,mean)
abline(h=1:2,lty=2,col="black")
points(meanvec,1:2, pch=17, col="red", cex=2)
```

Where `mydata` is a dataframe of observations with 3 columns:

- `socialanxiety`: The level of social anxiety of the patient
- `sex1`: the gender of the patient

Here is a code snippet to recreate some sample data.

```
n <- 100
mydata <- data.frame(socialanxiety=rnorm(n), 
       sex1=sample(c("male","female"),n,replace=T))
```

PS: these are fictional data.

Thank you in advance

Comment: We can't do much without some sample data. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5619526).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
mydata <- data.frame(socialanxiety=rnorm(n), 
           sex1=sample(c(1,2),n,replace=T))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=sex1, y=socialanxiety)) +
 geom_point(pch=0, size=3) +
 stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "red", geom = "point", aes(group=sex1), size=5, pch=17)+
 geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.numeric(sex1)), lty=2) + 
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2), labels=c("F", "M")) +
 coord_flip() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this is exacly what I was looking for. Thank you !